JavaFX, problemas para crear archivo jar en neatbeans
Estoy creando un proyecto JavaFX en Neatbeans y deseo crear un jar para ejecutar la aplicación, pero a la hora de darle en "Clean and Build" dentro del IDE, no me genera el archivo jar en la carpeta dist del proyecto. En consola me sale este mensaje, que supongo que algo tendrá que ver.
"Java 15 has removed Nashorn, you must provide an engine for running JavaScript yourself. GraalVM JavaScript currently is the preferred option."
Estoy usando la versión JDK 21 de Azul que incluye también las librerías de JavaFX.
Trate por mi propia cuenta averiguar una solución según lo que me recomienda este mensaje, sin embargo, me ha sida bastante difícil y sigo con encontrar una solución clara.

Una pregunta, ¿necesitas Nashorn en tu proyecto? Si no lo necesitas, entonces configura tu proyecto para que no lo use. Si lo necesitas, entonces lee este artículo, donde encontrarás la información necesaria para migrar a GraalVM JavaScript. El motivo de tu error es que, como dice el enlace anterior Nashorn se ha eliminado de JDK15. Ver también JEP 372.

Realmente desconozco que tienen que ver Nashorn y GraalVM con mi proyecto, pues soy estudiante y simplemente lo que deseo es poder crear el archivo jar para ejecutar mi aplicación fuera de NetBeans. "Unable to create javax script engine for javascript"  Este es otro mensaje que me da la consola que apunta a la ruta del proyecto y al archivo "jfx-impl.xml".

Por eso te pregunto,  pues son herramientas para escribir aplicaciones que usen Javascript. Si no es el caso, saca esas librerías de la configuración de tu proyecto. Te recomendaría que uses Maven si no lo estás haciendo ya, pues te facilitaría incorporar a tus proyectos las herramientas que necesites,  así como la generación de tus archivos finales.
